# NEXT13 Server action for show more pagination

Tags: pagination, next.js13

I have been working to place most of my sire as pre rendered non client side parts but the major hang up I have is managing a show more button.  I have a prisma query with 500+ items and I want to show 15 on render, then add 5 more each time the show more is used.

This part is a wrench in the system but would love to be able to make these random, Prisma does not have a rand() operator and I know I would also need to send the list of id's on each next request to not include them again.

Current test code

```
import { revalidatePath } from "next/cache";
import Link from "next/link";
import prisma from "@/client";

let pageId = 4
export default async function page() {
  async function addItem(formData) {
    'use server'
     pageId = Number(formData.get('pageNumber')) + 1
     console.log(pageId)
     revalidatePath("CURRENT PATH");
  }
  return (
    <div className="md:container mx-auto text-sky-700 dark:text-white">
      <div className="py-6 px-1">
        <div className="container mx-auto">
          <div className="flex text-sm gap-1 font-medium  items-center md:gap-4">
            <span>
              <Link href="../">AFC Home</Link> / PAGE
            </span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="md:px-24 py-8 text-center mt-2 p-2">
      <h2 className="text-3xl font-semibold px-8 md:text-6xl md:">
        Header
      </h2>
      <p className="py-6 font-medium md:text-xl md:my-10">
        TEXT
      </p>
      <form action={addItem}>
       <input type="hidden" name="pageNumber" value={pageId} />
      <button type="submit">Add more to {pageId}</button>
    </form>
      </div>
     
    </div>
  );
}
```

I have not found any documentation for pagination at all using server actions so any insight on implementing this is appreciated.

SO this code works, it incriments the pageId and I used it with a prisma query with success but revalidatePath('/current') does not just append the data it appends the data and puts me back on the top of the page.  I did not think that would happen

Comment: Code here "works" as in I can take the page number and update the query. I dont think appending matters if this is rendered on the server but the revalidate path is the issue essentially  putting the users b ack to the top of the page,.  Would transition on the div be possible?

Comment: This code Does work!  I was getting non ordered results from prisma from my order by (different issue?) but when prisma return the same order hydration works as expected.

Comment: So was too happy too fast, generatStaticParams breaks this :(